# Podmetrics not getting scraped into prometheus-operator

Tags: prometheus, monitoring, kubernetes-pod, prometheus-operator

I am currently working on setting up PodMetrics on a sample application [Link](https://github.com/brancz/prometheus-example-app)

The application is deployed fine this is the deployment.yaml file I am using currently

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: prometheus-example-app
  name: prometheus-example-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: prometheus-example-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: prometheus-example-app
        prometheus.io/scrape: 'true'
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: prometheus-example-app
        image: quay.io/brancz/prometheus-example-app:v0.3.0
        ports:
        - name: web
          containerPort: 8080
```

This is my Podmonitor.yaml file.

```
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: PodMonitor
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: prometheus-example-app
  name: prometheus-example-app
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: prometheus-example-app
  podMetricsEndpoints:
  - port: web
```

My prometheus operator is not reflecting any targets. This is the deployment file I used for prometheus operator

```
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: Prometheus
metadata:
  annotations:
    argocd.argoproj.io/sync-wave: "1"
  name: prometheus
  labels:
    name: prometheus
spec:
  serviceAccountName: prometheus
  serviceMonitorSelector: {}
  serviceMonitorNamespaceSelector:
    matchLabels:
      prometheus-scrape: "true"
  podMonitorSelector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: prometheus-example-app
  resources:
    requests:
      memory: 400Mi
  enableAdminAPI: false
  additionalScrapeConfigs:
    name: additional-scrape-configs
    key: prometheus-additional.yaml
```

I am not able to see the target or details related to the Pod reflecting in the config
Can anyone please help me out regarding this.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this all happening in the same namespace or in different ones? Because if the latter is the case, you need to be explicit about the `podMonitorNamespaceSelector` as you can see in the CRD: ```              podMonitorNamespaceSelector:
                description: Namespace's labels to match for PodMonitor discovery.
                  If nil, only check own namespace.```